# Stack Overflow Favorite Tags Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-watching

When I click the edit button next to Favorite Tags and add a succession (2+) of tags and reload the page, all the separate tags appear as one big tab globbed together. For example, if I type in c#, click add, type in python, click add, and refresh the page, I will have a tag that says c#python, and NOT two separate tags. I tested this in both IE and Chrome, and the same thing happens in both.